# MDADM Raid Recovery and Questions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, raid, mdadm

I've been working through this in my head for the entire day, and wanted to branch out and get some feedback/opinions on this setup, and how I can handle it if it ever happens to fail.

I have a Ubuntu Server system in which the filesystem lives on a relatively small disk by itself, and the main data that it stores sits on 5 disks configured in RAID5 using MDADM.

The data that is stored in the RAID array is medium priority.  There doesn't exist any sensitive personal user data, so a loss wouldn't mean the end of the world.  However, I would like a little bit of redundancy as I grow the drives, so RAID 5 is the obvious choice.

So, if a drive in the array fails, I can potentially replace it before anything catastrophic happens.  If another drive fails while the first is being replaced, then I just got struck by a bolt of unlucky lighting.

What I'm wondering about is what I can do with the drive that contains the OS.  Right now, what I'm doing is using rsync to back up the data to a remote location once a night.  And once a week, that remote location tars the filesystem up, and stores it (it will always keep 4 of the newest tarballs).  My logic is that this results in the lowest traffic between boxes, which is good since the server resides at my house, and yet I'll have sort of "full" weekly backups on the remote end as well as a nightly backup.  The rsync line in my backup script is as follows:

```
rsync --info=progress2 --numeric-ids -aAXPve ssh /* <remote>:~/server_backup --exclude=~/Download/* --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/lost+found --delete
```

Anyway, I've encountered drives failing on the RAID array.  It's easy, and feels satisfying knowing that all you have to do is swap it out, tell MDADM that you replaced the drive, and wait a day or two for the new drive to be completely added to the array.  I've yet to encounter the filesystem drive failing, however.  Which is why I'm here trying to get opinions/feedback on what I should do.

I considered adding another small drive for the OS, and mirroring the two using RAID 1.  The upside, I guess, is that if one drive completely hoses up, the other will save my filsystem.  The downside is that if there's some sort of corruption, or I really really mess something up, the data is immediately mirrored between both devices.  Basically I like the idea of having incremental and full backups more than a mirrored setup for the filesystem.

Okay, but so what happens that faithful day when the filesystem drive eventually does fail?
I go to the store, buy a new drive, plug it in, then what happens?

Do I have to install Ubuntu on the drive, and reverse the rsync command?
What happens to my RAID partition?
This is kind of a round-about way of asking, where does the RAID *metadata* get stored?
Was it on the OS drive?  Did it make it to my remote repository that holds the incremental backups via rsync?  Does it solely reside in the superblock on the RAID drives themselves?

If I go and get a new drive for the filesystem, install Ubuntu, and add it back into my server, what will it see?  Will it see the array at all?

If I then rsync all my changes back from the remote backup server to my local server, will it *then* see the array?

Or am I wrong in assuming either case?

I want to be prepared for when this drive finally dies.  I've been diligent in doing rsync off-site backups, but I want to know for sure if all of what I've been doing is a huge waste of time, and what I can do to assure I can continue using my system after a catastrophic failure of the drive that holds the filesystem.

Comment: 1) if the raid is failing often i think you should have a raid10. raid 10 is a mirror of 2 raid5's. As for making **full** backups every night might be a bit overwhelming. you should only make backups for when something changes. 2) The only way to get the OS to work off a raid 1 is to have a hardware raid controller, it wont work with `mdadm` as its a _software_ raid controller. these are a lot of questions. If your OS were to die or get corrupted, the info for the raid is stored on the OS. So installing another OS wont do any good if the original raid config was on the old OS that went bad

Comment: again, understand that youre dealing with a _SOFTWARE_ RAID controller. So to avoid losing the RAID configuration if the OS dies, i to have a hardware RAID. NOW, you can get a little more complex and backup the OS itself in case _that_ goes wrong, then you might have a better chance of not losing the RAID configuration.

Comment: Now dont get me wrong. A software RAID _is_ workable but theres a lot of maintenance as explained that take place to make sure that its reliable.

Comment: I got one bunk drive when I built the machine, and used mdadm to replace the drive.  I don't want anymore redundancy than RAID 5.  Also, `rsync` only copies differences in the OS over to the remote machine, not full backups.

Your first comment addresses what I was asking: "If your OS were to die or get corrupted, the info for the raid is stored on the OS. So installing another OS wont do any good if the original raid config was on the old OS that went bad".  I'm backing up my OS drive nightly, so that means, if I rsync it back, I should have back my raid configuration, right?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I have 6 drives: one holds the OS by itself, not in any RAID configuration, and the other 5 are in RAID 5.  If I lose the array due to faulty drives, oh well.  But I don't want to lose the array because the OS drive stops working if I have backups.

Comment: Correct. It should.

Comment: Thanks. I know it was a long post to ask a short question, but I wanted to see if anyone had any better feedback to what I'm doing.

When I built this some 2 or 3 years ago, I did a lot of research on RAID controllers, and hw vs sw.  What I concluded was you have to spend a lot of money on a hw RAID controller that can do better than sw.  Since this is only a media server, and I'm very familiar with Linux, I decided to go the sw route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array metadata is stored on each and every partition or drive that is a raid member, in an area known as the superblock. You probably want to look at the raid wiki for more details about that. eg you might look at it with

```
mdadm --detail /dev/sdc1
```

ref https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#RAID-1

ref https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#The_Persistent_Superblock_.282011.29

Provided you are using traditional raid layout (ie no caching etc), You should be able to reassemble the raid5 under a clean OS install without issue.

A reminder, raid arrays are all about uptime, not backups.

ref http://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&m=135811522817345&w=1

If the amount of data on the OS drive is small, and you can respond quickly, doing a restore may be fast enough for your use case. And you can keep the precious drive bay for other things (eg making the raid5 bigger).

You might even just pre-create a backup bootable drive so you can power off, swap out the drive and power back on. Make sure to refresh and test that once every quarter or monthly so it doesn't get too stale.

If you want to move to a raid1, there are a few different ways to get there, they all just need a little patience and a downtime window. I've linked an example below. There are numerous similar results available with a quick google.

ref https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-10.04

Comment: Excellent information and insight. This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: As an aside, this is a home media server.  The reason I chose RAID instead of JBOD is because if 1 drive failed in the latter case, all the data on that drive is gone, full stop.  With the RAID setup, if a drive fails, statistically speaking, it seems I would have a better chance of replacing it and not losing anything.

If I lose everything, as I mentioned in another comment, oh well. It's just media.  I keep all my repos and high priority data backed up via other means.

Comment: I don't have enough rep on super user to edit my comments, but basically, in a system in which I don't care about uptime or bullet proof backups, I would still prefer a RAID array over something like JBOD.